# What password to set when creating social user's account in Spring Security?

Tags: java, security, authentication, spring-security, oauth

I have a basic login with Spring Security (with tables 'users', 'user_roles' etc). I am adding social login (FB, Google, using their Javascript library. Not using Spring Social). So, when such a user successfully logs in from FB, Google etc, I need to create their account in Spring Security. I am setting their email as the 'username' field in 'users' table. What password should I set in the 'users' table for such users? A random string?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you set a random password, how could you use the account? Why do you create an account after log in? What is the reason for the account?

Comment: "successfully logs in from FB, Google etc" - here I meant logs in successfully into FB, Google and gets token and comes back to my app. I didn't mean that the user successfully logs in into my app. And I plan to log in the user into SS programatically, which doesn't require password, but it's a mandatory field in table, so I need one. Reason for the account is that I found it's a practice to create a user in SS when there is a social login. But I couldn't find anything about the password bit.

Comment: Why is the password a mandatory field? It's your database and you can change it.